Are moderators actions bound by site policies, or are they subject to personal interpretation?
When it comes to removing AI-generated content from the site (as stated here), some moderators choose to break with this policy, and decline flags raised for questions containing AI-generated content.
As an elected moderator, are you bound to follow SO policies, or are you free to interpret them as you see fit?
For a flag I raised, I got the following answer:

Declined - "I wrote most of the code myself" is not an admission of
using an AI. Even if it were, our policy on Qs about AI code is clear
from the mod answer on that meta Q. If you disagree, post a new meta
Q.

This response made reference to this Meta Q/A, which is not really illuminating, given that most (if not all) AI-generated content does not consist in full questions, but in code snippets within those particular questions, leading to fruitless debugging efforts.

Was it declined on a whim or was it declined because the moderator examined the flag and the content and concluded it was not AI generated? Because your question implies that any flag for AI content should be actioned in favour of the flagger. Which can't really be the case with flags.

My question is a generic one, @VLAZ. See this question for example, from where I cannot make up my mind whether as a Mod you're free to ignore SO policies, or not. Hence my question.

OK, so generically, are you asking whether mods are allowed to decline a flag after examining it and finding it has no merit? Or are you trying to set a "trap" where somebody answers you "of course they aren't" and then you spring "A-ha! But they declined this"?

I'm not going to comment your reasoning in asking are you setting a "trap". I'm asking about cases where there is clear AI generated content in question, and flag is still declined.

As an elected Mod, are you bound to follow SO policies, or are you free to interpret them as you see fit? Yes.

This discussion could be much more useful if you ask about the specific post that had the declined flag because details matters in these cases. It is not black and white, it is many shades of gray.

Then it would become specific, and I actually wanted to know the answer to my question. For a flag I raised, I got ``` Declined - "I wrote most of the code myself" is not an admission of using an AI. Even if it were, our policy on Qs about AI code is clear from the mod answer on that meta Q. If you disagree, post a new meta Q.```` This refers to this Meta post. I don't think that particular post is clarifying the situation at all. Much like your Yes answer above, @rene

That still needs context. Mods are janitors, exception handlers. They handled the specific exception. You now want to discover what extra guidance needs to be added so similar cases like the one you ran into are either handled differently going forward, or handled the same where this Q/A is the sign-post for flaggers in the future that run into declined flags for the same case. That needs specifics so others can relate.

The context is the fact some mods will action a question containing AI generated content, as per current policy, while others will leave it, based on the reasoning that question is about AI (which to me makes no sense). This makes it harder for someone to decide whether to flag a question or answer containing AI generated code. @rene

So, there is relevant context. Add that to the question so it becomes answerable. Otherwise my yes will be all you get, and many more declined flags, obviously.

@BarrythePlatipus if the question itself is AI generated flag, if the question asks about code that was generated by AI don't flag.

@AbdulAzizBarkat nobody generates questions with AI. Many though will generate code with AI, implying that code was written by themselves, leading to fruitless debugging efforts and so on -- all the reasons AI generated content is banned on site.

@BarrythePlatipus people do generate questions using AI. One type of person that does that is spammers, other is people who are trying to use AI generated posts to earn reputation.

Also you partly get the intent behind the ban wrong. Generative AI is banned because people can use it to flood the site with content at a pace they normally wouldn't be able to. This flood is a problem because the content posted looks good at a general glance but is very likely to be incorrect.

I understand the intent @AbdulAzizBarkat. People do flood the the site with good looking code snippets, which on a closer look make no sense. It's the effort behind that closer look which is frustrating. Why would you think I get the intent behind the ban wrong?

You state "leading to fruitless debugging efforts and so on -- all the reasons AI generated content is banned on site." which doesn't convey the intent of the policy properly. About the fruitless debugging effort that's the case even with questions that aren't generated by AI, such questions should simply be closed, we don't need to depend on the generative AI ban for that.

The difference here @AbdulAzizBarkat is that AI generated content is instantly generated and require no efforts from the poster, so site can be flooded with such content.

@BarrythePlatipus this has been widely discussed on the Meta post you linked, if the moderators declined a flag citing that, they are just following community consensus. If you disagree it would be better to post an answer there to discuss that.

Moderators generally enforce the site policy, their interpretations of the policy though might differ. In cases where people disagree with a moderator action, on the basis of their interpretation of a policy, a question can be asked on meta to discuss that. This might result in the action being reversed or it being considered correct.
About the specific flag you're talking about the moderator is at least correct in declining the flag. It seems the only evidence you had of generative AI usage was the following statement: "I wrote most of the code myself". This is not a proper admission of AI usage and can simply mean that some of the code was written by their colleagues or teammates. Unless there is proper proof or self-admission of generative AI usage a moderator isn't going to take any action on a post or user for that.
About the "policy on Qs about AI code is clear from the mod answer on that meta Q" that is widely discussed here and the community consensus (the opinion of the majority as seen by the answer scores) agrees with what the moderator stated. If you disagree with it you should post an answer on that question so that the community can vote on it.

That flag would have been declined  regardless of code being AI generated or not. Even if it were... -- don't cherrypick the mod reply.

@BarrythePlatipus the third paragraph in the answer covers that, please discuss that on the correct Meta post if you disagree.

No offense, but you're not answering my question. You're only repeating what was inconclusively written in the question you're making reference to. Ultimately, that's fine. Whatever.

@BarrythePlatipus: please be specific. How is this answer "not answering my question"? No, never mind. Fine. Whatever.
